# Combining verbs in Apache CXF JAX-RS

Tags: rest, jax-rs, cxf, cxfrs

We would usually define POST and PUT verbs as different service APIs.

```
@POST
@Path("/getbook")
@Produces({"application/xml","application/json"})
@Consumes({"application/xml","application/json","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})
public Response getBucket() {
...        } 
@PUT
@Path("/getbook/{name}")
@Produces({"application/xml","application/json"})
@Consumes({"application/xml","application/json","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})
public Response getBucket(@PathParam("name") String name) {
...        }
```

Would there be a way to combine these verbs into a single method - and then drive different logic based on the type of the verb ?
Hypothetically

```
@POST 
@PUT
@Path("/getbook/{name}")
@Produces({"application/xml","application/json"})
@Consumes({"application/xml","application/json","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})
public Response getBucket(@PathParam("name") String name) {

if(verb=POST){
...        }
else{

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this using `MessageContext`. You need the context injected into the service method like below for `updateCustomer` method and then you can check for the method type as you like (here I am checking for PUT):

```
@Path("/customer")
public class CustomerService {

    @Context
    private org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.MessageContext mc; 

    @PUT
    public Response updateCustomer(@Context MessageContext context, Customer c) {
        HttpServletRequest request = context.getHttpServletRequest();

        boolean isPut = "PUT".equals(request.getMethod());
    }
}
```